# Google Api Client - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Tags: flask, docker-compose, youtube-api, google-api-client

My code was working up until I decided to move my Google Api credentials into my Docker env. I'm using Flask as a web server framework.

This is my set up:

> DOCKER:

**docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
environment:
  - FLASK_ENV=development
  - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
  - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/project/api/resources/youtube/urls/project-84a0ef4dcd33.json
```

> FLASK:

**config.py**

```
 class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
```

**video.py**

```
from project.config import DevelopmentConfig

CREDENTIALS = DevelopmentConfig.CREDENTIALS
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = DevelopmentConfig.YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = DevelopmentConfig.YOUTUBE_API_VERSION

def youtube_id(track_name):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, credentials=CREDENTIALS,
    developerKey=None)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=track_name,
    part="id,snippet",
    ).execute()

    videos = []
    videos_ids = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
            videos_ids.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
        elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
            channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
        elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

    return videos_ids[0]
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

what is wrong, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path to `project_xxxxx.json` set in `docker` environment (the 'string') must be passed into `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file()`:

for clarity sake, change variable name in **config.py**:

```
PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
```

then, import `service_account` into your **video.py** module, like so:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

and:

```
GET_CREDENTIALS = DevelopmentConfig.PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS
PASS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GET_CREDENTIALS)
```

Finally, pass credentials, like so:

```
youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, credentials=PASS_CREDENTIALS,
    developerKey=None)
```

This will work.